# Firestore Get documents in order when querying using where in property

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
db.collection('myCol').where('id','in',['A','B','C']).get();
```

After querying it as above... I get the documents in random order between ***A, B and C***.

I would like my documents to be in order as  `['A','B','C']`

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the documentation on [ordering and limiting data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data):

```
db.collection('myCol').orderBy("id").where('id','in',['A','B','C']).get();
                    //
```

Comment: will it work if my array is `['B','A','C']` ?

Comment: I think so, as the documents are returned in the order they come from the index (which is based on the `orderBy` and not on the filter). Did you try it?